# Reading file line by line in listbox

Tags: c#

I tried to make my own email sender, but now I have issued to execute the mail list line by line. My current code is

```
foreach (string emails in listBoxEmails.Items)
{
    mail.From.Add(new MailboxAddress(textBoxSendName.Text, textBoxSendFrom.Text));
    mail.To.Add(new MailboxAddress(emails));

    client.Send(mail);

    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

I want the the program run like, after I sent the 1st mail of the list was successful, it will send the second mail. but from my code that I got from google, it will directly sent all the email together.

Comment: why not let `Send` return `bool` value (if `Send` is *successful* or not) and check it? `if (!client.Send(mail)) break;`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko: if client is SmtpClient, then Send method returns void. May be it's better to check for an exception.

Answer (score 0):

You should write a method something like that returns true or false.

```
    foreach (string email in listBoxEmails.Items)
    {
        if (!sendMail(textBoxSendName.Text, textBoxSendFrom.Text, email)){
            break;
        }
    }

    private bool sendMail(string name, string from, string to)
    {
        try
        {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.????.???");

            mail.From = new MailAddress(from, name, Encoding.UTF8);
            mail.To.Add(to);
            mail.Subject = "Test Mail";
            mail.Body = "This is for testing...";

            SmtpServer.Port = 587;
            SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
            SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

            SmtpServer.Send(mail);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {   
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I already tried this but the result is same http://prntscr.com/u1vfh6 . It sent directly to all the email list. I want to make it like after success sent the 1st then it will sent the second line. and for the lines counting it use for line++ for sent each line of email but I still can't get the logic. btw i'm sorry for my bad English.

Comment: I think your success criteria is that the email reaches the recipient, right?